# How to prove the sum of combination is equal to $2^n - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, combinations, exponentiation, factorial

One of the algorithm I learnt involve these steps:

$1$. define a set $S$ of $n$ elements

$2$. form a subset $S'$ of $k$ choice from $n$ elements of the set $S$ ($k$ starts with $1$), which is effectively the combination of $n$ choose $k$: $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$3$. repeat until $k = n$

So for example: $n=5, s = \{A,B,C,D,E\}$

1. 1st round:

   ```
   {A},{B},{C},{D},{E}

   (k=1 => n!/k!(n-k)! = 5 outcomes)
   ```
2. 2nd round:

   ```
   {A,B}, {A,C}, {A,D}, {A,E}, 
   {B,C}, {B,D}, {B,E}
   {C,D}, {C,E}
   {D,E}

   (k = 2 => n!/k!(n-k)! = 10 outcomes)
   ```
3. 3rd round:

   ```
   {A,B,C}, {A,B,D}, {A,B,E}
   {B,C,D}, {B,C,E}
   {C,D,E}, {C,D,A}
   {D,E,A}, {D,E,B}

   (k = 3 => n!/k!(n-k)! = 10 outcomes)
   ```
4. 4th round:

   ```
   {A,B,C,D}, {A,B,C,E}
   {B,C,D,E}
   {C,D,B,E}
   {D,C,A,E}

   (k = 4 => n!/k!(n-k)! = 5 outcomes)
   ```
5. 5th round:

   ```
   {A,B,C,D,E}

   (k = 5 => n!/k!(n-k)! = 1 outcomes)
   ```

The total outcome $t = 5 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 1 = 31$

Which correspond to the formula $2^n - 1$ (predicted by the algorithm)

So I was trying to prove that the sum of this series will result in $2^n - 1$ but did not succeed

series s

```
    s = n!/1!(n-1)! + n!/2!(n-2)! + ... + n!/(n-2)(n-(n-2))! + n!/(n-1)(n-(n-1))! + n!/n!(n-n)!

    s = n!/1!(n-1)! + n!/2!(n-2)! + ... + n!/(n-2)2! + n!/(n-1)1! + n!/n!

    s = n!/1!(n-1)! + n!/2!(n-2)! + ... + n!/(n-2)2! + n!/(n-1)1! + 1
```

could we prove the series above = $2^n - 1$?
Or am I on the wrong side of the road?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Binomial theorem? Namely, $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^kb^{n-k}$. Apply it with $a=b=1$, so that you get $2^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at Binomial theorem first

Comment: The formula is more symmetric when established with a $0^{th}$ round with $k=0$.

Answer (score 23):

The binomial theorem states that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k=(1+x)^n$$
Putting $x=1$ gives 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk=2^n\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk=2^n-1$$

Answer (score 9):

Taking all the rounds together (including the $0^{th}$), you have formed all combinations with any of the five letters taken or not, which you can do in $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$ ways. (Equivalently, all five bits numbers from $00000$ to $11111$, which is exactly $2^5$.)

For perfect rigor, one should show that there are no repetitions nor omissions.

Comment: +1Though the binomial theorem approach is easier, this approach shows why it ought to be true.

Comment: Note that the sets you're counting under this approach include the empty set.  This set wasn't in the original list, so it should really be $2^5 - 1$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: I wrote "including the $0^{th}$", which refers to my comment in the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:  Ah, that's what that means.  You might consider adding that to this answer explicitly, since sometimes overly hasty people (like myself) skip over the comments on the original question.

Comment: That's right @PaulSinclair, I want a "intuitive" view of the reason behind :), Yves explanation is pretty much like the one down there as well, I think I understand the issue now, thanks every one

Answer (score 8):

Let's consider the meaning of $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right).$ You are interested in the number of ways to construct a non-empty subset from the original set of $n$ elements.

Consider the set with $n$ elements, for each element, we have two options, to include it in one of the subset or not. If we allow our subset to be empty, the number of possible subset is $2^n$. To ensure that our subset is non-empty, we exclude the empty set,hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right)=2^n-1$$

Comment: Could you explain a little more about this part: "Consider the set with n elements, for each element, we have two options, to include it in one of the subset or not. If we allow our subset to be empty, the number of possible subset is 2n"

Comment: From set $S$, we want to construct a subset (which can be empty), say $B$. One possible to constuct a subset is to visit each element and consider whether to include it in $B$ or not. For element, there are two possible outcome, whether it is in $B$ or not. If each decision is independent and we have two decisions at each step, we end up with $2^n$. This procedure include the empty set as well, hence we exclude it later.

Comment: Would it make things clearer to add that each subset of S can be uniquely identified by a binary number
00001: {A}

00010: {B}

00011: {A,B}

00100: {C}

00101: {A,C}

00110: {A,B}
00111: {A,B,C}
01000: {D}
...
11111: {A,B,C,D,E}.  Having established a 1:1 correspondence between the binary numbers [1..11111] and the non-empty subsets, we thus prove the count thereof.

Comment: Ah! I think I understand now, @SiongthyeGoh, looks like you are using permutation (with repetition) to solve the problem.
<br>
Say we have *n* slots
<br>
    A B C D E
<br>
<br>
and for each slot we can have option of *0* or *1*  (zero means not chosen, 1 means chosen), and this in turn is a permutation with repetition problem, which is of *k^n* where *k=2* here