# How many ways can a flute be fingered?

Tags: combinatorics

Having trouble with this. Let's consider a flute with 6 holes. There's 1 way to play with no holes covered, 6 ways to play with exactly 1 hole covered, 15 ways to play with exactly 2 holes covered...and that's as far as I can think out.

But I can see that it will be symmetric. So covering 4 holes, there's 15 ways. 5 holes is 6 ways. All 6 holes, obviously there's only one way to do that.

I want to sum up all those ways. Sum = 1 + 6 + 15 + a + 15 + 6 + 1 = 44 + a. a is all the ways to play with 3 holes covered.

I'm sure this has been explored before but I don't know exactly what the combination or permutation or other terminology is. I believe this is a sum of multiple combinations. Anyway, I certainly cannot come up with a mathematical formula for it.

I also want to do this for a 8-hole flute. What is the answer and why?

Comment: Google binomial coefficients

Comment: The answer is 2^n. for 8 holes it is 256 ways

Comment: Instead of summing the combinations just think an hole as a binary digit: it can be closed or left open. Now it is pretty easy to understand that the number if possible fingerings is the count of all the values you can represent with $n$ binary digits, that is $2^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is a combination. These are represented by binomial coefficents:

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

$\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects (holes in a flute covered) form the $n$ objects in total (total holes in a flute), where you can't choose an object more than once (you can't cover a hole in a flute more than once) and the order in which you choose doesn't matter (it doesn't matter for the sound in what order you put your fingers on the holes).

$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ because there are $n$ ways to choose the first object, $n-1$ to choose the second form the remaining objects, $n-2$ to choose the third form the remaining objects, ... , $n-k+1$ to choose the $k$th form the remaining objects.

So there are $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ possibilities, but we didn't take into account that the order doesn't matter, so we need to divide by $k!$ (the number of ways to order $k$ choices) to get the formula 
$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

---

Note that the sum in your question is just missing one value. It should be $1+6+15+a+15+6+1$, with $a = \binom{6}{3} = \frac{6!}{3!3!}  = \frac{720}{6 \cdot 6} = 20$.

You can also see that, for example, $\binom{6}{2} =  \frac{6!}{4!2!} \frac{720}{24 \cdot 2} = 15$.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the sum now. Interesting that it's a sum of binomial coefficients. So 2*(1+6+15) + 20 = 64. For 8 it would be 256. Why is this? With triangular numbers, I figure summing up some series would just yield another triangular.

Comment: See this question @DrZ214: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782383/how-to-prove-the-sum-of-combination-is-equal-to-2n-1

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use -

$$\binom nr$$

You can see if cases start reflecting after one point.

Case 1 -

If total number of things are odd then total cases are n+1 including case with 0.

You have to find for $\frac{n+1}2$ cases and multiply by 2.

Case 2 -

If total number of things are even then total cases are n+1 including case with 0.

You have to find for $\frac{n-1}2$ cases and multiply by 2. Then add case $\frac{n+1}2$.