# How to infer the number of subsequences of array equal with the number all combination of array?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have an array of size $n$. I want the number of all subsequences of it (contains empty).

For example: $[1, 2, 3]$ 's all subsequences are $[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]$, So the number of all subsequences is $8$.

---

Using dynamic programming, it can be easily inferred: just choose $1$ or not, the result should multiply $2$, then choose $2$ or not, multiply $2$... So it will be inferred:

- $dp[n] = dp[n - 1] * 2 $
- $dp[0] = 1$

So the result is $2^{n}$

---

Another approach is by combinatorics. The result should be:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} C^{i}_{n}$$

---

In a word, how to infer:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} C^{i}_{n} = 2^{n} $$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782383/how-to-prove-the-sum-of-combination-is-equal-to-2n-1